# How to test for uniqueness of value in array in Yup?

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, formik, yup, react-functional-component

I have created a dynamic form with validation in React with Formik.

**What I have achieved so far:**

Current code allows users to selecting the number of tickets to purchase and then entering the name and email of the person each ticket is for, both fields are required and the email field must contain a valid email address.

The "Buy Tickets" button simply displays the form values in an alert popup if the form is valid, and the "Reset" button resets the form back to it's initial state including the removal of all ticket name & email fields.

**Issue:** I want to add uniqueness amongst my members value. Like, If user selected 2 from drop down than Form will ask for Member name and email 2 times, If in the first Member field, user enters "abc" and in the second number of member column, user enters "abc" than it should show error like 'Member value must be unique".

I have followed this [**Link**](https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/345) from Github but unable to achieve this with my code, I guess I am missing some step here.

**Code Link:** https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-glp2dw?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.jsx%3A71%2C26

How can I achieve this with my existing code?

### Edit 1 - Structure Change:

=> I have implemented this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77827861/21957513) and it worked. But, Now I have an array of strings instead of array of objects, which is look like this.

Sample Object:

```
const initialValues = {
  numberOfTickets: "",
  tickets: [
    "Ticket 1",
    "Ticket 2",
    "Ticket 3",
    "Ticket 4",
    "Ticket 5",
    "Ticket 6",
    "Ticket 7",
    "Ticket 8",
    "Ticket 9",
    "Ticket 10",
  ],
};
```

=> What changes should I implement in the validation schema, the onChangeTickets function, and the Yup.addMethod to achieve the same goal? My objective is to ensure that each array element is both unique and required."

**Updated code with Yup.addMethod Method:**
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-pztv4s?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.jsx%3A56%2C9-56%2C16

Answer (score 1):

So with that solution you need to run this code once in your application

```js
  Yup.addMethod(Yup.object, "uniqueProperty", function (propertyName, message) {
    return this.test("unique", message, function (value) {
      if (!value || !value[propertyName]) {
        return true;
      }

      const { path } = this;
      const options = [...this.parent];
      const currentIndex = options.indexOf(value);

      const subOptions = options.slice(0, currentIndex);

      if (
        subOptions.some(
          (option) => option[propertyName] === value[propertyName]
        )
      ) {
        throw this.createError({
          path: `${path}.${propertyName}`,
          message,
        });
      }

      return true;
    });
  });
```

The solution will be like this

```js
import React from "react";
import { Formik, Form, Field, FieldArray, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

let setupYupCallOnce = false;
function setupYup() {
  if (setupYupCallOnce) return;
  setupYupCallOnce = true;
  /* The code above */
}

function App() {
  /* ... */

  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    numberOfTickets: Yup.string().required("Number of tickets is required"),
    tickets: Yup.array().of(
      Yup.object()
        .shape({
          name: Yup.string().required("Name is required"),
          email: Yup.string()
            .email("Email is invalid")
            .required("Email is required"),
        })
        .uniqueProperty("name", "Repeated name")
        .uniqueProperty("email", "Repeated email")
    ),
  });

  /* ... */

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setupYup();
  }, []);

  return (
    /* ... */
  );
}

export { App };
```

Comment: Hey, this worked in this case, but Now I have changed my object structure. Please review the 'Edit Part' section of the question where I have provided additional details. I would greatly appreciate your assistance in resolving this matter.

Comment: I have added more details in question with label 'Edit 1 - Structure Change'.

Comment: I didn't get the issue
You have an array of strings in the initial value, couldn't you just manipulate the array to fit the form?

Comment: You're right and I tried in  same way by manipulating array. But, Sadly it was not worked. I am able to achieve my output in a object format which will have keys as name and it's values, But Now I want to use Array of strings. I have mentioned new array structure in my question with label 'Edit 1 - Structure Change". Can you please modify this code to achieve same outcomes. Thanks in Advance. To understand my scenario in a detailed way, just open this link and I have added description in App.jsx starting part. Have a look: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-hooks-counter-demo-forked-pztv4s